# How to have scrapy 2.x logs in JSON format?

Tags: json, logging, scrapy

I'm trying to format scrapy's logs in JSON format. For that I have tried multiple things,

- First, to use `"LOG_FORMAT": "%(asctime)s [%(name)s]": "%(levelname)s: %(message)s",`

But with that, I still have to add brackets at the beginning and the end of the file + handle multi-line logs (remove all \n). And even with that, it didn't work because I couldn't manage to change the format of the **Tracebacks**

- The second idea was to rewrite the logs in the wanted format in the `def closed()` doing something like that:

  ```
   "LOG_FORMAT": "%(asctime)s [%(name)s]:: %(levelname)s: %(message)s",

   ...

   def closed(self, reason):
       import json
       dict_json = {}
       json_logs = open(self.custom_settings["LOG_FILE"].replace(".log", ".json"), "w")
       with open(self.custom_settings["LOG_FILE"]) as file:
           lines = file.readlines()
           for line in lines:
               if f"{datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} " in line:
                   key, value = line.strip().split("::", 1)
                   dict_json[key] = value
               else:
                   dict_json[key] += "\n" + line.strip()

       dict_json["stats"] = str(self.crawler.stats.get_stats())
       json.dump(dict_json, json_logs, indent=4, sort_keys=False)
       json_logs.close()
  ```

It does work as expected but it doesn't make sense to write logs than rewrite them with the expected format...
Does anyone think of a smarter way to do this ?
Thanks in advance